# Question About Pluck Results in Laravel 5.7

Tags: laravel, laravel-query-builder, laravel-5.7, laravel-collection

I have a question about the `pluck` method in Laravel. How can I get the following result in a list?

`Name + Lastname + id`

I use this line command in a controller

Line: `$choferes`

```php
public function index()
{
    $asignaciones = Asignacion::orderBy('id', 'ASC')->get();
    $choferes = Chofer::orderBy('id', 'ASC')->pluck('nombre', 'id');
    $dueños = Dueño::orderBy('id', 'ASC')->pluck('nombre', 'id');
    $asignaciones->each(function ($asignaciones)
    {
        $asignaciones->chofer;
        $asignaciones->dueno;
    });

    return view('admin.asignaciones.index')
        ->with('asignaciones', $asignaciones)
        ->with('choferes', $choferes)
        ->with('dueños', $dueños);
}
```

The result in a list:

```
1 => "name 1"
2 => "name 2"
```

However, I need to combine: `name` and `lastname`. It needs to be a list. How can I display it in my view?

```
<div class="col-xs-6">
    {!! Form::label('chofer_id','Lista de Choferes') !!}
    {!! Form::select('chofer_id[]', $choferes, null,
        ['class'=>'form-control select_chofer',
        'multiple',
        'required','id'=>'list_chofer']) !!}
</div>
```

I have this result:

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tOQdM.jpg)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `Chofer` model define

```
public funcion getFullNameAttribute()
{
    return $this->attributes['first_name'] + ' ' + $this->attributes['last_name'];
}
```

In controller use this

```
$choferes = Chofer::orderBy('id', 'ASC')->get(['id`, ...])->pluck('full_name', 'id');
```